# Is there a pattern to convert dynamically between formats?

Tags: java, json, xml, etl

My task is to create a pipeline for converting different types of input like:

- RESTful[JSON, XML, ...]
- Socket [JSON, XML, ...]
- RDBMS
- ...

then use the output they give me to do transformations and things and send them back to the same or another source/format/structure in the end. Is there a pattern to assist in this situation and make it as abstract as possible, so I can just switch the object, no matter the source and structure? The response object is always a form of collection: JSONArray with multiple Objects, ResultSet, ...

My idea was to create a 'adapter class', which is able to accept a JSON string, a XML string or even a RDBMS dataset so I can work with this adapter object and then convert it back to another structure: JSON String, DataSet, ...

```
class AdapterClass
{
    //how could it look like?
}

class AdapterClassFactory
{
    //input
    public AdapterClass generateByJSONString(String input)
    public AdapterClass generateByXMLString(String input)
    public AdapterClass generateByResultSet(ResultSet input)
    public AdapterClass generateByCSV(String input)

    //output
    public String generateJSONString(AdapterClass input)
    public String generateXMLString(AdapterClass input)
    public ResultSet generateResultSet(AdapterClass input)
    public String generateCSV(AdapterClass input)
}
```

I think I just got a kind of brain lag, but I just don't get the answer in my head. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Underscore-java library has static methods U.xmlToJson(xml) and U.jsonToXml(json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you describing can be done by a integration framework like [Apache Camel](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/README.md). It can consume data from different sources [REST](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html), [JDBC](https://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html) and [many other](https://camel.apache.org/components.html). Also, it can transform data to/from any format, so it's highly customizable.

For example, you can build a pipeline like

> read data from  a REST endpoint -> unmarchall JSON to POJO class -> do some transformation -> marshall POJO to XML -> send data to another service